# Maximum number of $k$-element subsets whose pairwise intersections consist of no more than 4 elements

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $M = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 36\}$. What is the largest number of $k$-element subsets of $M$, such that all possible pairwise intersections of these subsets consist of no more than 4 elements?

I have to solve the problem for $k = 12$.

Thank you in advance!